# Can I power 2 Servos with Raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, servo

I'm working with 2 servos (SG-5010) and I want to use my Raspberry Pi 3 to control those servos. Can I power those 2 servos with the 5V pins (pins 2 or 4 in rasp)?

I'm powering my Raspberry Pi with a power supply of 5.1 V and 2.5 A.

PS: I can't find the max current consumption of the servo in the datasheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, but not reliably, you will better off using a separate external power supply.

I have driven such servos from the Pi's power supply but the load was very light, the servos were not required to generate much torque.  If the servo is required to generate a high torque it will probably try to draw more current than the Pi can supply causing a system crash when the Pi voltage drops too low.

Comment: I think my servos are going to draw little current. On top of servo 1 is going to be servo 2 and a camera, and on top of servo 2 is going to be the camera. So I think I need little torque.

Comment: I just in case I can move one Servo at a time, so do you think is ok to power the servo with the raspberry pi?

Comment: You will have to try and find out.  The worse I expect is a Pi reboot which **may** lead to a corrupted SD card image.